# Ajuda em função para deletar os valores repetidos contidos em uma Lista duplamente encadeada em C

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Não estou conseguindo desenvolver uma função dentro do meu código que retire os valores duplicados dentro de uma lista duplamente encadeada, poderiam me ajudar?

Segue o código feito até o momento, a função que preciso corrigir é a `retiraValor`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lista {
float valor;
struct lista* anterior;
struct lista* proximo;
} Lista;

/* Criar uma lista vazia */
Lista* criarLista(){
return NULL;
}

/* Insere no inicio da lista*/
Lista* inserirNaLista(Lista* list, float valor){
Lista* novo = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
novo->valor = valor;

if (!list){
    novo->anterior = NULL;
    novo->proximo = NULL;
}
else {
    novo->anterior = NULL;
    novo->proximo = list;
    list->anterior=novo;
}

return novo;
}

/* Imprime na tela os valores*/
void imprimirLista(Lista* lista){
Lista* proximaLista;
for (proximaLista=lista; proximaLista!=NULL; proximaLista = proximaLista->proximo){
    printf("\nO valor da lista e: %.2f", proximaLista->valor);
 }
}

/* Busca um determinado valor na pilha*/
Lista* buscarNo(Lista* list, float valor){
Lista* proximaLista;
for(proximaLista = list; proximaLista != NULL; proximaLista = proximaLista->proximo){
    if (proximaLista->valor == valor){
        return proximaLista;
      }
   }
 }


Lista* retornaTopo(Lista* list){
Lista* temp = list->anterior;
if (temp->anterior != NULL){
    return retornaTopo(temp);
}
else{
    return temp;
  }
}



/* Retira um nó conforme o valor informado*/
Lista* retirarNo(Lista* list, float valor){
/*Ponteiro para o n? anterior*/
Lista* anteriorLista;
anteriorLista = criarLista();

/*Ponteiro para percorrer a lista*/ 
Lista* proximaLista;
proximaLista = criarLista();

proximaLista = list;
while (proximaLista != NULL && proximaLista->valor != valor){
    anteriorLista = proximaLista;
    proximaLista = proximaLista->proximo;
}

// Nao achamos o valor
if (proximaLista == NULL){
    return list;
}

if (anteriorLista == NULL){
    list = proximaLista->proximo;
    proximaLista->proximo->anterior = NULL;
}
else{
    if (proximaLista->proximo == NULL){
        anteriorLista->proximo = NULL;
        if (anteriorLista->anterior != NULL){
            anteriorLista = retornaTopo(anteriorLista);
        }

        return anteriorLista;
    }
    else{
        anteriorLista->proximo = proximaLista->proximo;
        if (anteriorLista->anterior != NULL){
            anteriorLista = retornaTopo(anteriorLista);
        }

        return anteriorLista;
      }
  } 
}



//ESSA EH A FUNCAO QUE NAO ESTOU CONSEGUINDO DESENVOLVER
void retiraValor(Lista* lista){
Lista* proximaLista;
float numero = proximaLista->valor;
for(proximaLista = lista; proximaLista != NULL; proximaLista = proximaLista->proximo){
    if (proximaLista->valor == numero){
        retirarNo(proximaLista, numero);
    }
  }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
Lista *lista;
lista = criarLista();

Lista *lista2;
lista2 = lista;

lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 6);
lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 10);
lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 7.25);
lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 5);
lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 10);
lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 23);
imprimirLista(lista);
printf("\n\n");

Lista* retira_n(lista2);
imprimirLista(lista2);


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dei uma olhada no seu algoritimo e fiz algumas modificações:

```
void retiraValor(Lista* lista) {
    Lista* minhalista = lista;
    while (minhalista != NULL) {
        Lista* innerList = lista;
        int equal = 0;
        while (innerList != NULL) {
            if (innerList->valor == minhalista->valor) {
                equal++;
            }
            if (equal == 2) {
                retirarNo(lista, minhalista->valor);
                break;
            }
            innerList = innerList->proximo;
        }
        minhalista = minhalista->proximo;
    }
}
```

Sua abordagem estava meio vaga, o processo de remover itens duplicados em uma lista desordenada duplamente encadeada é bastante custoso. No algoritimo basicamente para cada item da lista, percorri a lista novamente a procura de mais de uma ocorrência do mesmo valor e utilizei a sua função **retirarNo** para tira-lo da lista.

Testei com a função **main** desta forma:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Lista *lista;
    lista = criarLista();

    Lista *lista2;
    lista2 = lista;

    lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 6);
    lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 10);
    lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 7.25);
    lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 5);
    lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 10);
    lista = inserirNaLista(lista, 23);

    imprimirLista(lista);
    printf("\n");

    retiraValor(lista);

    imprimirLista(lista);

  return 0;
}
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Felipe Nascimento, Você é o cara, te agradeço muito pela sua ajuda e cooperação, resolveu meu problema em sua totalidade, estou aprendendo ainda sobre listas encadeadas, estou com um pouco de dificuldades, mas testei incansavelmente resolver sozinho antes de pedir auxilio.    Muito obrigado, fica com Deus.

Answer (score 1):

Sua função retiraValor() só está pegando o primeiro valor da lista e verificando se ele está duplicado. Se a intenção é remover todas as duplicatas, é necessário iterar entre *todos* os valores da lista e, para cada um destes, verificar se há outro no restante da lista com o mesmo valor.

Outra coisa é que a retiraNo() está demasiadamente complicada... Em tese, ela deveria apenas receber um nó, retirá-lo da lista atualizando os ponteiros e liberar a memória dele (com um *free()*, que ficou faltando no seu código).

Comment: Emoon, muito obrigado pelas dicas, vou dar uma trabalhada em cima disso, Obrigado.